# Sitecore ECM AutomationStatesStatisticsByMessage

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecm

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 + EXM 3.1.1.

After installation of the QA server and some test payload, the table "Fact_AutomationStatesStatisticsByMessage" in Analitycs DB remains empty. There're no errors in Log files event in the DEBUG mode. I expect some data in the table because the table is updated on our DEV servers and reflects the number of sent/opened messages.

Any ideas, why?

Comment: Have you checked that connection between Mongo DB Server and the QA server is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did figure it out.

There is a collection named "AutomationStateDefinition" in Mongo "Analytics" DB. It is supposed to be filled with all Automation States of all *active* Email Campaigns. It was empty on the new installed environment because I didn't copy Mongo Databases to the new environment, I just wanted them to be empty. However if this collection is empty Sitecore is not able to update the "Fact_AutomationStatesStatisticsByMessage" SQL table.

Actually the log saying something like:
"ERROR Unable to get automation state definition"

That might be a problem when you install new environment. The solution for me was **deactivate** and then **activate** each Email in EXM. The Mongo "AutomationStateDefinition" collection is filled with records once you activate EXM Email.